# Failure while parsing ZonedDateTime#toString() with Joda time

Tags: elasticsearch, java-8, jodatime

With Elasticsearch 1.x (1.7.5 depends on Joda time 1.6), I could use the custom date time format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ[ZZZ]" to parse serialized strings obtained with ZonedDateTime#toString() (such as '2016-11-29T18:47:21.766+01:00[Europe/Paris]') into timestamps.

With Elasticsearch 2.4.1 (which depends on Joda time 2.9.4), I cannot anymore. It fails with a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-11-29T18:47:21.766+01:00[Europe/Paris]" is malformed at "Europe/Paris]"" exception.

EDIT : this is about the Elasticsearch Java API.

EDIT2 : I simply would like to translate Java 8 DateTimeFormatter#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME into a format string that could build a working Jodatime FormatDateTimeFormatter using Joda#forPattern(String, Locale)

I reproduced the issue in a TestNG test case :

```
final ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
final String strNow = now.toString();
final FormatDateTimeFormatter formatter0 = Joda.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ[ZZZ]", Locale.ROOT);
formatter0.parser().parseMillis(strNow);
```

That code snippet fails with the following exception :

> FAILED: parseMillisTest
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-11-29T18:47:21.766+01:00[Europe/Paris]" is malformed at "Europe/Paris]"
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:826)
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterTest.parseMillisTest(DateTimeFormatterTest.java:27)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1137)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)

1. Am I wrong to believe that Joda Time 2.9.4 is faulty in that respect ?
2. In the hope I am indeed wrong, what could be the correct format to parse such '2016-11-29T18:47:21.766+01:00[Europe/Paris]' strings ?

Comment: This works for me in Elasticsearch 2.4.2: `PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ[ZZZ]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST test/test/1
{"date":"2016-11-29T18:47:21.766+01:00[Europe/Paris]"}`

Comment: The issue is in the Java API. I am going to edit the question to precise that.
And still there in 2.4.2 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from jodatime 2.9.4 to jodatime 2.9.5 solved the issue.
With Elasticsearch 2.4.2 (which depends on jodatime 2.9.5) the problem is gone. I just ran again my tests and they pass.

I tried again the test with a dependency on jodatime 2.9.4 and it fails. 2.9.5 works fine.
Do not consider my last comment, which is wrong. I must had done something wrong with the dependencies.